# Error on DOM travesal javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

why am I getting an error on the below code. The error says. Please advise. I want to move up the chain until I find tag "h2".

> **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null"**

```
var z =document.querySelector('input[id="nf-field-448"]');
x=z.parentElement;


       while(!x.querySelector('h2'))

        {    
            if(x.previousElementSibling !== "null")

                { 
                   x = x.previousElementSibling;

                }


            else 
                {

                 x = x.parentElement;

                   }

        }

        alert('true');
    }
```

Comment: If there is no parent H2, then you'll eventually reach the top of the DOM tree and both `x.previousElementSibling` and `x.parentElement` will return null. Attempting then to do `x.querySelector(...)` will throw your error. Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code seems to go to the first element that has an H2 descendent (i.e. where `x.querySelector('h2')` returns true), it doesn't stop at the first H2 it finds (i.e. where `x.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'h2'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite your function like this does it help?

```
var z = document.querySelector('input[id="nf-field-448"]')
x = z.parentElement

while (!x.querySelector('h2')) {
  x = x.previousElementSibling || x.parentElement

  if (!x) console.log(`
    x is undefined
    - previousElementSibling ${x.previousElementSibling}
    - parentElement ${x.parentElement}
  `)
}
```

Comment: but the code always goes to the topmost H2 tag and not the immediate avaible H2 element. can you please let me know why? In the below page https://www.capgemini.com/service/new-ways-to-accelerate-innovation/ there are 3 Submit buttons and i need the title corresponding to the button which was clicked which is in H2 element. what should i do.

Comment: I imagine that you are not allowed to change html right? Because adding a data-ref='id_of_your_title' would be much straightforward.

Comment: Or what if you go up until the .article_text item and then $('.article_text').find('h2') or articleText.find('h2') ?

Comment: Thanks for the help i have made slight change to the code. It was my error. var z = document.querySelector('input[id="nf-field-448"]')
x = z.parentElement

while(x.tagName!="H2") {
  x = x.previousElementSibling || x.parentElement
 
}

alert(x.textContent);